# How do you zoom in and out while on a Skype call?

Tags: webcam, skype

I am using a Logitech Webcam Pro 9000 and Skype 2.2.0.25 and Ubuntu 11.04. I can not figure out how to zoom in and out during a video chat, although it is possible under windows using Logitech's software. Is this function supported under Skype and Ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: I think the problem is because Logitech does not provide its proprietary software for Ubuntu or Linux for that matter. But you can still refer to these articles I had found when I too faced a similar problem. http://logitech-en-emea.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9266/section/troubleshoot/crid/435/lt_product_id/5867/tabs/1,3,2,5/cl/gb,en/kw/

Answer (score 9):

I didn't find how to do this directly in Skype, but I could do this with a third-party GUI software: [`v4l2ucp`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/v4l2ucp/) (which you can [install with this link](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/v4l2ucp)). It is a control panel for v4l which normally handles Logitech webcams (my HD Pro C920 was supported out of the box).

Here is what it looks like:

[image: v4l2ucp control panel]

At the very bottom you have a `Zoom, Absolute` cursor that will allow you to zoom in and out, and adjust other settings too. The changes are reflected in real time in Skype.

As a small bonus, I wrote the following script to zoom in 150%, and set the video format to 1080p@30fps:

```
#!/bin/sh
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=zoom_absolute=150
v4l2-ctl --set-fmt-video=width=1920,height=1080,pixelformat=1
v4l2-ctl --set-parm=30
```

saved it to a file and set it to run automatically when my session starts. 150% is what worked best for me, and I can still change it dynamically with v4l2ucp whenever I want.

Comment: Fabulous!  Just worked for me though the zoom on my particular Logitech only seems to do 1x or 2x.  But 2x does the job in OBS.

Answer (score 2):

The old keyboard shortcut works for many programs; give it a try while you have Skype open:

```
Ctrl +
```

From terminal you can try the video adjustment package that's [listed](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/) as supported for your model:

```
guvcview -o
```

Read more about it [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype).  To [install](http://guvcview.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) guvcview:

```
sudo apt-get install guvcview
```